# Transpose table if column was created by `create on use`

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am trying to transpose a table where one column was created using `create on use` however the second row of the transposed table doesn't show up, the vertical separation bars are missing and also the math mode is ignored for the $x$ in the transposed table. Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
x  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
}\mytable

\pgfplotstableset{
  create on use/y/.style={
    create col/expr={\thisrow{x}^2}
  }
}

\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type,
    colnames from=x,
    input colnames to=x
]\mytablenew{\mytable}


Original table:

\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={x,y},
columns/x/.style={column name=$x$},%
columns/y/.style={column name=$y$},%
]{\mytable}
\end{center}


\vspace*{1ex}

Transposed table:

\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    %rows={x,y}, %doesn't work
    every head row/.style={
        after row=\midrule
      },
      every column/.style={column type={l|}},
      every last column/.style={column type={l}},
      row/x/.style={row name=$x$},
      row/y/.style={row name=$y$}
    string type]{\mytablenew}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: you can't tranpose a table with a `create on use` because it is not on use at that time. You can save it as a new table and transpose that one instead of typesetting

Answer (score 2):

- For the created y-column you can work with 
  `\pgfplotstablesave[columns={x,y}]{\mytable}{mytable1.dat}` 
  and transpose this table.
- The head of the added table is the 0. column of the transposed table, so you have to say 
  `display columns/0/.style={
  column name=$x$, 
  string type,
  postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={$##1$} },%<-- new
  }`

**Alltogether:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread{
x  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
}\mytable

Original Table:
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\mytable}
%
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/y/.style={
create col/expr={\thisrow{x}^2}
}}
%
Added Table:
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={x,y},
columns/x/.style={column name=$x$},
columns/y/.style={column name=$y$},
]{\mytable}

\pgfplotstablesave[columns={x,y}]{\mytable}{mytable1.dat}%<-- !
Saved Table: 
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{mytable1.dat}
%
\pgfplotstabletranspose[%columns={x,y},
    colnames from=x,
    input colnames to=x,
]\mytablenew{mytable1.dat}%<-- new,   old: \mytable
\bigskip

Transposed Table: 
% Suggestion:
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1.5em}|} 

\pgfplotstabletypeset[%string type,%<-- new 
every head row/.style={after row=\hline%<-- new,   old: \midrule
},
% every column/.style={} % I do not found this command in the manual
every even column/.style={column type=L },
every odd column/.style={column type=L },
every last column/.style={column type=L },
display columns/0/.style={
column name=$x$, 
string type,
postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={$##1$} },%<-- new
},
]{\mytablenew}

\end{document}
```